# Flutter - I have two issue with RadioListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with RadioListTile it doesn't work when I make the change that does not change unless I leave it and return to it I find it changed.

The second problem is I want to save the option when the application is run for the first time, it is the first choice.

if someone has answered, please?

this is my code:

```
int radioValue = 0;
int tafIbnkatheer = 1;
int tafBaghawy = 2;
int tafQurtubi = 3;
int tafSaadi = 4;
int tafTabari = 5;
var showTaf;

void handleRadioValueChanged(int val) {
    TranslateRepository2 translateRepository2 = new TranslateRepository2();
    TranslateRepository translateRepository = new TranslateRepository();
    TranslateRepository3 translateRepository3 = new TranslateRepository3();
    TranslateRepository4 translateRepository4 = new TranslateRepository4();
    TranslateRepository5 translateRepository5 = new TranslateRepository5();

    setState(() {
      radioValue = val;
      switch (PrefService.getInt('$radioValue')) {
        case 1:
          setState(() {
            showTaf = translateRepository2;
          });
          break;
        case 2:
          setState(() {
            showTaf = translateRepository;
          });
          break;
        case 3:
          setState(() {
            showTaf = translateRepository3;
          });
          break;
        case 4:
          setState(() {
            showTaf = translateRepository4;
          });
          break;
        case 5:
          setState(() {
            showTaf = translateRepository5;
          });
          break;
      }
      print(showTaf);
    });
  }



@override
  void initState() {
 setState(() {
      radioValue = 1;
    });
 super.initState();
 }


  ...
    RadioListTile(
      value: tafIbnkatheer,
      groupValue: radioValue,
      title: Text("Radio 1"),
      subtitle: Text("Radio 1 Subtitle"),
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
           handleRadioValueChanged(val);
        });
      },
      activeColor: Colors.red,
      selected: true,
    ),
    RadioListTile(
      value: tafBaghawy,
      groupValue: radioValue,
      title: Text("Radio 2"),
      subtitle: Text("Radio 2 Subtitle"),
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
          handleRadioValueChanged(val);
        });
      },
      activeColor: Colors.red,
      selected: false,
    ),
    RadioListTile(
      value: tafQurtubi,
      groupValue: radioValue,
      title: Text("Radio 3"),
      subtitle: Text("Radio 3 Subtitle"),
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
           handleRadioValueChanged(val);
        });
      },
      activeColor: Colors.red,
      selected: false,
    ),
    RadioListTile(
      value: tafSaadi,
      groupValue: radioValue,
      title: Text("Radio 4"),
      subtitle: Text("Radio 4 Subtitle"),
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
           handleRadioValueChanged(val);
        });
      },
      activeColor: Colors.red,
      selected: false,
    ),
    RadioListTile(
      value: tafTabari,
      groupValue: radioValue,
      title: Text("Radio 5"),
      subtitle: Text("Radio 5 Subtitle"),
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
           handleRadioValueChanged(val);
        });
      },
      activeColor: Colors.red,
      selected: false,
   ),
...
```

Comment: Please explain better

Comment: The RadioListTile doesn't work and how I can save the choice?

Comment: You are making a excessive use of the setstate method. You are calling setstate in the Radiolisttile's onChanged method, and then you trigger setState again in handleRadioValueChanged. This is going through a sort of loop in building your UI. I'm not completely sure of what you are trying to do (since there's code missing) but I can suggest you to try removing all those setStates...you put a setState inside initState too! Why? InitState is run before calling build() (e.g. Before building a state), so there's no state to set!

Comment: I delete all setState but it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

To make a Radio List Tile selected, as the documentation says, you can use checked. In fact

checked → bool
Whether this radio button is checked

selected → bool
Whether to render icons and text in the activeColor.

Comment: I think this for just activeColor

Comment: Be aware: checked is a READ ONLY property: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile/checked.html